How can I create .deb file from VSCode's source code (Code - OSS)
I'm getting an error when creating .deb file after building Code - OSS for linux
I followed all the steps from How to Contribute guide in the official vscode repository.
This step did complete just fine (takes about 42mins)
$ npm run gulp vscode-linux-x64
But when I try to create .deb file for easy installation using
$ npm run gulp vscode-linux-x64-build-deb
I get this output (error), and I have no idea why it's happening. Any help would be appreciated!
> code-oss-dev@1.97.0 gulp
> node --max-old-space-size=8192 ./node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js vscode-linux-x64-build-deb

[22:09:08] Using gulpfile /workspaces/vscode/gulpfile.js
[22:09:08] Starting 'vscode-linux-x64-build-deb'...
[22:09:08] 'vscode-linux-x64-build-deb' errored after 6.99 ms
[22:09:08] Error: spawn /bin/sh ENOENT
at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:285:19)
at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:483:16)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)

